# Framework of Windows 7 Service Pack 1

Tags: windows

I'm looking for this information but can't find it anywhere !

What is the framework setup by default when upgrading to Windows 7 Service Pack 1 ?

Thanks for your help and sorry if this a dumb question ;)

Comment: Are you asking which .NET Framework version is installed with Win7 SP1?

Comment: Yes ! I don't want to setup a new virtual machine to find this out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nerver mind ! I manage to find it.

Windows 7 SP 1 include frameworks 1.0, 1.1, 2.0, 3.0 and 3.5 (https://superuser.com/questions/298025/does-windows-7-have-net-4-installed-by-default)